# Admin Menu - Highlight top-level menu when on a sub-menu page (without showing sub-menu)

Tags: admin-menu, sub-menu

This is the current situation:

- I am writing a plugin that has a top-level menu page
- The plugin also contains other sub-menu pages
- The sub-menu pages are not assigned a parent slug (thus they do not appear in the admin menu)

My requirement is to do the following:

- Have only the top-level menu page menu item in the admin menu (no sub-menu page menu items should appear)
- Highlight the top-level menu page menu item when on a sub-menu page

---

I've tried giving a parent slug to the sub-menu pages. This, of course, makes it appear as expected under the top-level menu item. I then tried to remove the sub-menu item, by using remove_submenu_page. However, since that removes the entire sub-menu page, it doesn't solve the problem.

I believe the logical thing to do, is to give a parent slug, since the top-level menu item will need to know that the page being accessed falls under it. The problem then, is not showing the sub-menu page's menu item. I am unable to find a function that deals directly with the menu items.

---

Is this the right approach or is there a better alternative? 
Is there a action/filter/hook I can utilise to carry out what I need to do?

**Edit #1:**
Did some further research/testing. Setting the menu_title parameter to null or '' in the add_submenu_page call makes the title not appear. However, the <li> that contains the sub-menu item still does exist and can be interacted with. When there are numerous sub-menu pages (as in my case), the empty <li> elements will add-up and create a long blank area on the menu. This is far from ideal and as such, I'm still searching for a solution.

**Edit #2:**
Tried manipulating the $submenu global after the comment from @s_ha_dum. However, any removal of the menu section pertaining to a page also results in removing the page similar to remove_submenu_page and thus rendering that page inaccessible.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105370/21376

Comment: Unfortunately, that method seems to work similar to [remove_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/remove_submenu_page) and makes accessing the page throw a "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." message. I'll check up further on it though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Would a tabbed interface within your main page achieve the same goal? http://getbutterfly.com/how-to-create-a-tabbed-interface-for-your-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I'm not entirely sure I want to have all the different pages (there are about 8 or so in total) loading in tabs though. I suppose I could do some AJAX loading where the individual page content is loaded as and when it is needed. I'm still interested in finding a solution for the original problem. However, I think it may not be possible for the current WP version without modifying the core files (which I do not wish to do). I'll check out the tabbed approach. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There's an easy way to resolve it here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-page-menu-item/

Answer (score 3):

That's a bit of a late answer and I don't know if @Jay ever sorted it out, but to anyone having the same issue, here's how I fixed it.

### Menu Pages

```
function my_admin_menu() {

    add_menu_page(
        'Page title',
        'Menu title',
        'manage_options',
        'my_page',
        null,
        null,
        99
    ); 

    add_submenu_page(
        'my_page',
        'Subpage 1 title',
        'Subpage 1 menu title',
        'manage_options',
        'my_subpage_1',
        null
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'my_page',
        'Subpage 2 title',
        'Subpage 2 menu title',
        'manage_options',
        'my_subpage_2',
        null
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' ) );

function my_admin_head() {

    remove_submenu_page( 'my_page', 'my_subpage_1' );
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_admin_head' );
```

See the Codex for [remove_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/remove_submenu_page).